# Attempting to connect to sql server on Android Studio "connection timed out"

Tags: android, sql-server

I have been attempting to connect to an sql server. Here is the code

```
package com.servebeer.blooddonations.canadianblooddonations;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Connection connect;
    public void initialize(){
        connect=CONN(<username is here>,<password is here>,"blooddatabase","70.75.191.26:3306");
    }
   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private Connection CONN(String user,String pass,String db,String server){
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy=new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn=null;
        String connUrl=null;

        try{
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            connUrl="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server + ";" + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + user + ";password=" + pass + ";";
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(connUrl);
            Log.w("Connection","open");
        }catch(SQLException se){
            Log.e("ERROR", se.getMessage());
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException cl){
            Log.e("ERROR", cl.getMessage());
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }

        return conn;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialize();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

However whenever I attempt to emulate the application I get this error

```
Network error IOException: failed to connect to /70.75.191.26 (port 3306): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

I have checked that the correct port is being forwarded (3306) and have tried with both my firewall enabled and disabled. I still get the same error. I am assuming something on my computer is stopped the connection, but I have spent hours trying everything I could think of with no luck.

These permissions are in my Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Here it is as an Async Task, still timing out.

```
 public void initialize(){
        //connect=CONN("root","","blooddatabase","70.75.191.26:3306");
        Connect();

    }
    public void Connect() {
        Connect task = new Connect();
        task.execute();
    }
        private class Connect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String response = "";
            String connUrl=null;
            String server="70.75.191.26:3306";
            String db = "blooddatabase";
            String user="<username>";
            String pass="<password>";

            try {
                Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
                connUrl="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server + ";" + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + user + ";password=" + pass + ";";
                Log.w("Connection","Starting");
                Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(connUrl);
                Log.w("Connection","open");

            } catch (SQLException se) {
                Log.e("ERROR", se.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
            }
            return response;
        }
            protected void onPostExecute(){
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should be doing the network call in an AsyncTask. That's probably why you're timing out.

Comment: Should I be extending AsyncTask in my CONN function then?

Comment: I tried changing it to an Async Task. I still get the time out message.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a session parameter, sometimes databases need a time frame to operate with the connection.

Answer (score 0):

The default port of SQL Server is 1433, if you haven't ever changed it, you don't need to specify the port number. However if you have changed it, you should use this format: `String server="70.75.191.26,3306";` using `,`  instead of `:`